# How to check condition using checkbox?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am trying to send value to server using json,what I am trying is when I select checkbox I want to send "Y",,in my json active=Y is status of user activation and deactivation,,following is code what i tried,but its not working,it always shows active=N

```
 proactives=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.edt_proactive);
     if(proactives.isChecked()==true)
      {
          proactives.setTag("Y");
      }
      if(proactives.isChecked()==false)
      {
          proactives.setTag("N");
      }
```

Comment: You want to use an else if

Comment: can anyone help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094070/how-to-create-parallogram-shape-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
proactives.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
            {
                proactives.setTag("Y");
            }
            if(proactives.isChecked()==false)
            {
                proactives.setTag("N");
            }
        }
    });
```

OR

```
proactives.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
              proactives.setTag(b? "Y" : "N"); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: proactives.isChecked()==true is not necessary, since isChecked already returns a boolean, which you are comparing with true. Also, since boolean b represents the checked value, doing proactives.isChecked() is also not needed, you could replace all that code with if (b) {...}else{...}

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183249/autocompletetextview-not-working

Answer (score 1):

you can use `OnCheckedChangeListener`

```
proactives.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // change your tag here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` :

```
proactives.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           // use isChecked value here to react to state changes on your checkbox
       }
   }
);
```

Comment: what is compound button?

Comment: The super class of CheckBox, see documentation here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183249/autocompletetextview-not-working

Answer (score 1):

give onclick in layout file

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/edt_proactive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="itemClicked" />
```

in your activity do this

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        proactives.setTag("Y");
    }else{
        proactives.setTag("N");
}
```

Comment: but by default i want to set uncheck my checkbox

Comment: yes it uncheck by default android:onClick="itemClicked" this line only mean click listener on this check box.

Comment: @2Dee what you want to modify this answer sir

Comment: The original formatting of the answer was incorrect, text was included in code blocks and code indentation was also messed up, so I corrected it for readability

Comment: @MdHussain can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183249/autocompletetextview-not-working

Answer (score 0):

faster way :P

```
proactives=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.edt_proactive);
proactives.setTag(proactives.isChecked() ? "Y" : "N");
```

edit: and use `OnCheckedChangeListener` as above answers mention

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: true, it doesn't... i've edited my ans a bit, but already there is accepted one