# How to send id of autocompletetextview?

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

In my application I used autocompletetextview to retrieve data,the data which I display is using json,now autocompletetextview works well,but what I want is after getting name in my autocompletetextview I want to send id of category,but it sends name..following is my response..and my snippet code is here..[Autocompletetextview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183249/autocompletetextview-not-working)

```
{
 "category":
  [
   {
      "id":"4",
      "name":"cat1"
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
    "name":"aditya"}
   ]
}
```

Add_Catagory.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btns;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private  MultiAutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
private static final String FEEDBACK_URL = "";
private static final String FEEDBACK_SUCCESS = "status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    acTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,acTextView.getText().toString()));
    acTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

   /* JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
    List<SuggestGetSet> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());
    list.get(0).getId();*/



    btns=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    });
}

     class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean failure = false;
    private String catid;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      //  pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();

        String pweighttype=acTextView.getText().toString();


        try {
              JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
              List<SuggestGetSet> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());
              for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
                if(list.get(i).getName().equals(acTextView.getText().toString()))
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parentid",list.get(i).getId()));
                System.out.println("Su gayu server ma"+params);
                catid=list.get(i).getId().toString();
              }


              System.out.println("Su catid"+catid);

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 FEEDBACK_URL, "POST", params);
             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
             final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");

            runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
             {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            });
             return json.getString(FEEDBACK_SUCCESS);

         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

        //parentcat.getText().clear();
}}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this//modify doInBackground

```
   try {
      JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      List<SuggestGetSet> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());
      for(int i = 0;i<list.length();i++){
        if(list.get(i).getName().equals(acTextView.getText().toString()))
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parentid",list.get(i).getId()));
           break;
      }
```

Comment: it shows Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: in which line you want to send id?

Comment: after getting text in my autocompletetextview...see in my do in background method..I am sending values to server..and have you check my edited class file..i edited your code..is that right?

Comment: id is sending but it send only id=4..i mean if i select 'aditya' yet it sends id 4..may it takes only 0th position..

Comment: it says red line under length()..The method length() is undefined for the type List<SuggestGetSet>......then i tried with size instead of length but it sends nothing..

Comment: it worked i removed break statement and use it with size..now it works well..accept and vote up..thanks

Comment: i mean as per your answer,i was able to get single item's id,,but now what I am trying is user should able to select more than one item and and then I want to get ids

Comment: see my edited question..and I am not allowing to ask more questions here.. so i ask here

Comment: i am busy now , i will check tomorrow ,sure :)

Comment: hello is it possible to get items from another search view? I mean I am getting client names using search view,and then after select client i am getting products of that client,now how can i display products also in another searchview?can you tell

Comment: actually, im busy now