# Xamarin Android Booking Calendar View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create view like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDE7.png

I have no idea how to create rotated rectangles on matrix.

I tried to do this with Fragments, where each fragment has

- header ListView(days of week)
- ListView of rows (where row contains
  two TextView with rectangle shape, which I can color).

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr1iX.png

Any suggestions?

Sorry for Paint ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094070/how-to-create-parallelogram-shape-background

Comment: When I do like in this article, all of the rectangles will be rotated. But I want e.g. only two

Comment: You can programatically apply the `android:background` to the View you want it on in that case. Should be able to use the `Background` property of any View: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Background/

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but I have to "draw" rotated rectangle on existing matrix. The result with this tip: http://s13.postimg.org/6oxhhelvr/stack2.png :/