# How to make parallelogram shape for button through xml?

Tags: android

Till now i used res/drawable/parallelogram.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="1%"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="1dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

But it makes triangle shape.
 Please save me.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create parallelogram shape background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094070/how-to-create-parallelogram-shape-background)

Comment: it's not the same.let's take top width=100dp, bottom width=80dp,height left and right 50dp like i have to make parallelogram.@Satan Pandeya